# PrimeVue DataTable Component #Filter slot not working

Tags: laravel, vue.js, primevue

I'm using PrimeVue within a Vue app and I'm specifically using the PrimeVue DataTable component.

Within the DataTable component when you are setting up the Columns there are slots within the Column component so you can have a header, body, footer, etc.

Well one of the slots used to be "#filter'. For some reason now when I try to use the "#filter" slot nothing happens. But I know it works because if I change the slot to footer the section appears at the bottom of the column.

Anyone else have an issue with the "#filter" slot? Did they get rid of it? I did update recently. However, when I look in the documentation it still shows that the filter slot exists in V2.10.2 (the version I'm on).
https://www.primefaces.org/primevue-v2/#/datatable

I tried moving the slot content to the footer slot and it worked. So I know the slot content is fine.

Update: Thanks for the suggestion to include some code. I can't include it all but I can provide enough to get the point across.

```
<DataTable
:value="tableData"
:alwaysShowPaginator="alwaysShowPaginator"
:paginator="paginator"
:lazy="true"
:loading="loading"
:rows="rows"
:totalRecords="totalRecords"
:sortField="sort.sortBy"
:sortOrder="sort.sortDir"
ref="dt"
dataKey="id"
class="p-datatable"
paginatorTemplate="FirstPageLink PrevPageLink PageLinks NextPageLink LastPageLink"
currentPageReportTemplate="Showing {first} to {last} of {totalRecords}"
@page="onPage($event)"
@sort="onSort($event)"
responsiveLayout="scroll"
:stripedRows="true"
 >
<template #empty>
    <div class="text-center">No matching records found.</div>
</template>
<template #loading>
    <div class="text-center">Loading data. Please wait.</div>
</template>

<Column
    v-for="col of columns"
    :field="col.field"
    :header="col.header"
    :key="col.field"
    :headerStyle="col.style"
    :sortable="col.sortable"
    :style="col.style"
>
    <template #filter>
        <InputText
            type="text"
            v-if="col.filter === 'text'"
            v-model="filters[col.field]"
            class="p-column-filter"
            placeholder="Search..."
            @keyup="onFilter"
        />
           <Dropdown
            v-if="col.filter === 'select'"
            v-model="filters[col.field]"
            :options="col.options"
            :showClear="true"
            placeholder="Select..."
            optionLabel="label"
            optionValue="id"
            @change="onSelect($event)"
            >
            </Dropdown>
        </template>

        <template #body="slotProps">
          {{ slotProps.data[col.field] }}
        </template>
    </Column>

    <template #paginatorLeft v-if="totalRecords">
        <div class="p-l-sm">Showing {{ from }} to {{ to }} of {{ totalRecords }} records</div>
    </template>
</DataTable>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I've added some code to give more context. Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure my issue is that the #filter slot is not working. I just don't know why. Was it removed in a recent update? was the slot name changed? or did I do something wrong?